# How to combine casting sql and key/value attributes in the same query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm

how would one combine these two conditions into the same params map for a query?

```rb
Post.where('created_at >= ?', 2.weeks.ago)
```

```rb
Post.where(:site_id => site_id)
```

Up until now I've just been building them like

```rb
Post
.where(:site_id => site_id)
.where('created_at >= ?', 2.weeks.ago)
```

but given this situation, I'm kinda stuck

```rb
# With the addition being the sql casting query
params = {:site_id => site_id}
Post.where(params)
```

I'm not sure how to do this, or what to even call it really.  Any help?

### Info

Rails 7.0 
Ruby 3.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Post
  .where(:site_id => site_id)
  .where('created_at >= ?', 2.weeks.ago)
```

translates to

```
params = { site_id: site_id, created_at: (2.weeks.ago..) }
Post.where(params)
```

by using an [endless range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges) for the date condition, that Ruby on Rails is able to translate in a coequal SQL condition.

Comment: Another thing to add is that you can also do this for both sides of the range.  Like `{created_at: (2.weeks.ago..4.weeks.ago)}`, and as well just the end range like: `{created_at: (..4.weeks.ago)}`.  So in essence, replacing both the "greater than or equal to" and the "less than or equal to".  Neat!

Answer (score 1):

You can use AND for both the created and site_id params in where Query.

```
Post.where('created_at >= ? AND site_id = ?', 2.weeks.ago, site_id)
```

Comment: Ok yeah I see this.  The main thing is that I'm updating old ruby syntax (1.9.3) to new ruby syntax(3.2.2), and the application has quite a bit of param maps with a sizeable amount of attributes in each.  spicks solution works well without having to modify ALL of the param maps into strings.

Comment: Yes, Exactly we do not have to modify the params.